# JavaScript loop appending data to formData - incremented variable showing the same with each loop in formData

Tags: javascript, form-data

I have a loop in JavaScript where I am appending multiple files to formData so it can be uploaded to an API call.
For each file the value in the **maxDiplayOrderHold** is to be one number higher than the previous file.

I confirmed that the the **maxDiplayOrderHold** value increases by 1 through each loop iteration using console.log.

The value being appended to formData every time is the value from the first loop iteration.
Below is my loop code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < imageFile.length; i++){                      
                                      
   maxDiplayOrderHold++;
   formData.append("imageFile", imageFile[i]);       
   formData.append("reportId", reportIdHold);
   formData.append("DisplayOrder", maxDiplayOrderHold);                                                 
   console.log("current maxDiplayOrderHold value: ", maxDiplayOrderHold);
   formData.append("CreateUser_ID", userId);
   console.log("fromData DisplayOrder",formData.get('DisplayOrder'));  //this is returning the same number each time
            
   }
```

I do not know why the same value is showing up for DisplayOrder in formData when the **maxDiplayOrderHold** value is increasing in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.get will get the FIRST entry

Move this to after the loop so you only set the value once

```
formData.append("DisplayOrder", imageFile.length);
```

You can do [getAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll) to get all the DisplayOrder entries

```js
const formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"))

const imageFile = new Array(4);

for (var i = 0; i < imageFile.length; i++){                      
   formData.append("DisplayOrder", i);                                                 
   console.log("fromData DisplayOrder",formData.get('DisplayOrder'));  //this is returning the same number each time
}
console.log(formData.getAll("DisplayOrder"))
```

```html
<form></form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of get. I can now see that the displayorder value is correct in the formData being sent to the API.